# Keeping the Batteries warm

Tags: backpacking

I carry a camera that has detachable batteries. I also carry an extra spare battery for my cellphone and a power bank.
Batteries discharge at colder temperatures.

How do I keep batteries warm so that they do not discharge due to extreme weather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution is keeping them close to your body somewhere within your clothing. This shouldn't be a problem with small items like phone batteries or small power banks. However, to make sure that they don't get damaged as your clothing gets damp from sweating, I would advise to pack them into some lightly waterproof container. An old plastic bag or a freezer bag will do.

Camera batteries (depends on the camera type) can be a different issue since they can be quite bulky, so carrying them in the pockets of your jacket might be a bit umcomfortable. Unfortunately they don't produce heat by themselves (if they do, get rid of them as soon as possible ;-) ), so just putting them somewhere into your backpack between your spare clothes to provide some insulation won't be enough and they would get cold rather quickly. However, if you pack some heat source with them, this might help. Consider for example one of those gel filled hand warmers that reversibly transform the gel into a solid while producing heat. That should be enough for several hours of cold exposure, especially, if the whole thing is surrounded by some insulation.